# How to find a page details like whether it has frame, table, link and how these are all embedded for automating any web application

Tags: html, dom, watir

I want to automate web application using watir or watir-webdriver. I get errors like unable to locate element even though I kept proper object details. So I have a doubt that whether I am keeping complete flow of object or not. I might miss parent fame, table etc so I want to know the object parent details also. Please help me to identify complete structure of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, I think you want to use your browser's developer toolbar.

The [Watir Wiki](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Browser-Development-Toolbar) includes information on starting the toolbar. Below is part of the wiki article.

> To view details of elements in your web application, it is recommended to use a developer toolbar as it will provide element inspection functionality. These quickly show you the element attributes and properties you need to know to automate them with Watir.
>
> The following browsers have development toolbars available:
>
> **Internet Explorer** (8 and later)
>
> Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools are included with the browser. Please see this article in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628.aspx) for documentation.
>
> **Firefox**
>
> The Developer Toolbar for Firefox is called Firebug, and is available
>   as a plug-in.
>
> 1. Visit http://getfirebug.com/
> 2. Click Install Firebug
> 3. Click Add to Firefox
> 4. Follow prompts and restart Firefox to enable add on
> 5. Click the bug icon to the right of the URL window of Firefox
> 6. Click the Inspect icon then any element in your app to see its
>      properties
>
> **Chrome**
>
> The Developer Toolbar for Chrome is included in the Chrome installation. Please see the [Chrome Developer Tools documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I know how to get the object details and information you provided is correct and I am doing the same. But my question is how to use them correctly in my code as I am trying with id, name, class, href but still i am unable to identify the element. see my code  browser.link(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click but its not working and i tried with element and tried with many options like. browser.element(:class, 'bpmWorkspaceFilterConditionsTable').element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').click

Comment: I see. Then I would suggest you create a working example that shows the problem - ie create an html page and watir code that allows us to reproduce the problem. It is extremely difficult to debug something that we cannot reproduce - ie those bits of watir code are valid, but could not be working for many reasons.

Comment: I am able to work with google search or gmail but the problem is in my application where they have built the application such a way that when ever I click one link then it will open dropdown frame/table with again inner frames/cells. I tried with root to child by using element().element.operation but I couldnt achieve my target. :(

Comment: Without a sample page that reproduces the problem, it is very difficult to help without making a lot of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I did using two level child node identification from the root.
First I have identified the object ID of frame and then I went into the element level.

```
browser.element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:_id246').select_list(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionsMenu').option(:value => 'caseId').select

browser.element(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:_id246').link(:id, 'portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionButton').when_present.click
```